# Elixir erlang :ftp.send got stuck

Tags: ftp, erlang, elixir

I use `Erlang` `ftp` lib in my elixir project to send file to ftp server.

I call `send` function `:ftp.send(pid, '#{local_path}', '#{remote_path}')` to upload file to ftp server.
Most of the time it uploads files successfully, but it sometimes stuck here, not moving to the next line.

According to the docs it should return `:ok` or `{:error, reason}`, but simply stuck at `:ftp.send`.

Can anyone give me suggestion? I am not familiar with `Erlang`.

Version: `Elixir 1.7.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 21)`

Answer (score 1):

`ftp` module has two types of [`timeout`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ftp.html#ftp-client-service-start-stop), both set during the initialization of `ftp` service.

Here is an excerpt from the documentation:

> **`{timeout, Timeout}`**
>   Connection time-out. Default is **`60000`** (milliseconds).
>
> **`{dtimeout, DTimeout}`**
>   Data connect time-out. The time the client waits for the server to connect to the data socket. Default is **`infinity`**.

Data connect time-out has a default value of `infinity`, meaning it’d be hang up if there are some network issues. To overcome the problem, I’d suggest you set this value to somewhat meaningful and handle timeouts in your application appropriately.

```rb
{:ok, pid} = :ftp.start_service(
  host: '...', timeout: 30_000, dtimeout: 10_000
)
:ftp.send(pid, '#{local_path}', '#{remote_path}')
```

Comment: thanks..the reason would be the default value of `dtimeout` as you mentioned...

Comment: Of course, it is, I don’t post wild guesses as answers.